# Is it possible to automatically compile a LaTeX document through terminal using TeXworks?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal, latex

I want to create an alias to automatically compile the main .tex file of a big document in LaTeX under Debian Wheezy.

That means I need a shell command to do so. Is this possible? I am currently using TeXWorks. I wouldn't mind if I had to use another program (Preferably similar to TexWorks).

I have revised the documentation of TexWorks but I haven't been able to find anything usefull.

Note: I know that this could be done by simply:

1. Using  *alias myalias='texworks ~/mydir/mydoc.tex'*
2. Then clicking on the *play* button.

But I specifically want a command to do both things.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not directly familiar with TeXworks and having had a quick look at it, I couldn't see an obvious way of automatically compiling your work.

In the past though, I've found the best way to achieve this is to use a 3rd party tool to continuously rebuild the document, and use a PDF viewer that detects the changed PDF and reloads it on change. On linux I use [latexmk](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/). You can start automatically recompiling with:

```
latexmk -pdf -pvc <mydocument.tex>
```

I found I had to configure latexmk to get automatic updating of the PDF to work. My very basic configuration:

~/.latexmkrc

```
$pdf_previewer = "start /usr/bin/mupdf %O %S";
$pdf_update_method = 2;
```

With the above configuration, when you save your LaTeX file in TeXworks, latexmk will automatically recompile the document and reload the mupdf viewer with your changes.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Amazing! I was using 

$ watch "latexmk -pdf <mydocument.tex>" 

which was not working recently for some reason recently